# What code do I need to add to open in a new window?

Tags: php, html

I have a pricetable plugin which opens the button links in the same window. I would like to have theme opened in a new blanc window. What code do I need to add in this file?

Also note that the links are generated by a wordpress plugin, so I can't add target="_blank" manually in the code.

Thanks for the help

```
<div class="price-columns">
    <div id="column-skeleton" style="display:none">

        <span class="ui-icon ui-icon-carat-2-e-w column-handle"></span>
        <a href="#" class="ui-icon ui-icon-trash submitdelete deletion"></a>

        <div class="type">
            <input type="radio" value="recommend" name="price_recommend" />
            <label><?php _e('Recommend', 'pricetable') ?></label>
        </div>

        <input type="text" class="column-title" name="" placeholder="<?php _e('Title', 'pricetable') ?>" />
        <input type="text" class="column-price" name="" placeholder="<?php _e('Price', 'pricetable') ?>" />
        <input type="text" class="column-detail" name="" placeholder="<?php _e('Detail', 'pricetable') ?>" />
        <input type="text" class="column-url" name="" placeholder="<?php _e('Button URL', 'pricetable') ?>" />
        <input type="text" class="column-button" name="" placeholder="<?php _e('Button Text', 'pricetable') ?>" />

        <h4><a href="#" class="addfeature"><?php _e('Add', 'pricetable') ?></a><?php _e('Features', 'pricetable') ?></h4>
        <div class="feautres">
            <div class="feature">
                <span class="ui-icon ui-icon-carat-2-n-s feature-handle"></span>
                <a href="#" class="ui-icon ui-icon-trash submitdelete deletion"></a>

                <div><input type="text" class="feature-title" placeholder="<?php _e('Title', 'pricetable') ?>"/></div>
                <div><input type="text" class="feature-sub" placeholder="<?php _e('Sub title', 'pricetable') ?>" /></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <?php // Existing columns of the price table ?>
    <?php foreach($table as $i => $column) : ?>
        <div class="column">
            <span class="ui-icon ui-icon-carat-2-e-w column-handle"></span>
            <a href="#" class="ui-icon ui-icon-trash submitdelete deletion"></a>

            <div class="type">
                <input type="radio" name="price_recommend" id="price_recommend_<?php print $i ?>" value="<?php print $i ?>" <?php if(isset($column['featured']) && $column['featured'] === 'true') print 'checked="true"'; ?> />
                <label for="price_recommend_<?php print $i ?>"><?php _e('Recommend', 'pricetable') ?></label>
            </div>

            <input type="text" class="column-title" name="price_<?php print $i ?>_title" value="<?php @esc_attr_e($column['title']) ?>" placeholder="<?php _e('Title', 'pricetable') ?>" />
            <input type="text" class="column-price" name="price_<?php print $i ?>_price" value="<?php @esc_attr_e($column['price']) ?>" placeholder="<?php _e('Price', 'pricetable') ?>" />
            <input type="text" class="column-detail" name="price_<?php print $i ?>_detail" value="<?php @esc_attr_e($column['detail']) ?>" placeholder="<?php _e('Detail', 'pricetable') ?>" />
            <input type="text" class="column-url" name="price_<?php print $i ?>_url" value="<?php @esc_attr_e($column['url']) ?>" placeholder="<?php _e('Button URL', 'pricetable') ?>" />
            <input type="text" class="column-button" name="price_<?php print $i ?>_button" value="<?php @esc_attr_e($column['button']) ?>" placeholder="<?php _e('Button Text', 'pricetable') ?>" />

            <h4><a href="#" class="addfeature"><?php _e('Add', 'pricetable') ?></a><?php _e('Features', 'pricetable') ?></h4>
            <div class="feautres">
                <?php if(isset($column['features'])) : foreach($column['features'] as $j => $feature) : ?>
                    <div class="feature">
                        <span class="ui-icon ui-icon-carat-2-n-s feature-handle"></span>
                        <a href="#" class="ui-icon ui-icon-trash submitdelete deletion"></a>

                        <div><input type="text" class="feature-title" name="price_<?php print $i ?>_feature_<?php print $j ?>_title" value="<?php esc_attr_e($feature['title']) ?>" placeholder="<?php _e('Title', 'pricetable') ?>"/></div>
                        <div><input type="text" class="feature-sub" name="price_<?php print $i ?>_feature_<?php print $j ?>_sub" value="<?php esc_attr_e($feature['sub']) ?>" placeholder="<?php _e('Sub title', 'pricetable') ?>" /></div>
                    </div>
                <?php endforeach; endif; ?>
            </div>
        </div>
    <?php endforeach ?>

    <div class="column addnew"><?php _e('Add Column', 'pricetable') ?></div>
    <div class="clear"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: If you want this to be in a separate window, why not have the link to this page include => target="_blank"

Comment: Ok, at every a href= I entered target="_blank" but with no luck. Where is this button rendered? the url is rendered from custom url's that are being entered in the backend of the wordpress plugin.

Comment: @gopi1410 I know about the target"_blanc", but because this did not work I thought lets ask this question here as it should be easy to answer for programmers like you guys ;-)

Comment: @Justmac: added an answer just now, check it. It should work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, if your links are generated by wordpress you may consider adding target attributes dynamically after the page loads. `Use the following script after page load or document ready`:

```
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">

function add_target()
{
   // Find all the anchors you want to modify
   var anchors = document..getElementsByTagName('a'),
   i = anchors.length;

   // Add the target to each one
   while(i--) anchors[i].target = "_blank";
}

</script>
</head>

<body onload="add_target()">
/* your body */
</body>
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, I realy appreciate it, but I feel like a complete noob because I have no idea where to add this. I thought it was a simple line of code added to the file, but I will hire my programmer to fix this i guess :-) Again thanks for the help ;-)

Comment: I thought this line had something to do with it, but I guess I was wrong. <input type="text" class="column-url" name="" placeholder="<?php _e('Button URL', 'pricetable') ?>" />

Comment: updated the code just copy paste the <script> part of the code in the head and modify the body attribute.

Comment: No, the input type has nothing to do with the links.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `target="_blank"` in the `<a>` tag.

Comment: Please do not pollute my answers with w3school links. See http://w3fools.com and [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/HTML/Element/a#Attributes) for a proper reference.

Comment: LOL. Didn't know w3schools is hated that much. I removed the link :)

Answer (score 0):

Add to each  
Target="_blank"
That's it.

Answer (score 0):

use `<a href="your_url" target="_blank">link</a>` in your code.